# AJAX call to php and fill table

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a table user in database.

It contains the fields: `id,username,password,email,phone`

I want to make an AJAX call from php to fill a table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>Nane</tr>
        <tr>Email</tr>
        <tr>Phone</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have tried a ajax code. That code justfills innerHTML of a div. I want to get something like object so that my table can be filled.

Comment: What's your Ajax code look like? What's your backing PHP look like?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the steps to get you started, and with a question like this there is ample information that is simple enough to find what your after.

1. search Stack Overflow for connecting to and retrieving data from MYSQL database (also search "PHP SQL select").
2. output data in your desired format. HTML?
3. Use jQuery Javascript library. Use inbuilt ajax functions like to request your script: $('tbody').load('script.php');

Comment: I found nothing except some android related code. Can you please give me a link.

Comment: Sure. There is a great code foundation on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php Google also returns alot of relevant articles